# Show ToolTip on DataGridView when cell value has changed

Tags: c#, datagridview, tooltip

I want to show a `ToolTip` when the value of a cell in a [`DataGridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) control is changed and the introduced value is invalid.

This can easily be done with the code below, but the problem is that after the `ToolTip` is shown, it is also associated with the control, so every time the `DataGridView` is hovered the `ToolTip` is displayed, and I want it to be shown only once after the data has been changed.

I have noticed that this happens only with `DataGridView` and `GroupBox`. With a `TextBox` or a `Button` the `ToolTip` is not associated with the control when shown over it.

Why does this happen?

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        this.dataGridView1.ShowCellToolTips = false; // so we can show regular tooltip
    }
    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView control = (DataGridView)sender;
        // check if control.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value is valid
        if (invalid)
        {
            toolTip.Show("Invalid data", dataGridView1, 5000);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to deal with this. The simplest and most direct seems to be to `Hide` the `ToolTip` when you are leaving the `DataGridView`:

```
private void dataGridView1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolTip1.Hide(this);
}
```

Of course it is up to you to decide upon the full design of what should happen while the error is still there..!

As for `Textboxes`: They are very special and there is usually no use in asking why they behave diffently..

Another way would be to code the Popup event and use the Tag as a flag to make sure it is shown only once:

Before you show it in the CellValueChanged you set a flag:

```
 toolTip1.Tag = "true";
```

and in the Popup event you check for it:

```
private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
{
    if (toolTip1.Tag == null) return;
    bool show = toolTip1.Tag.ToString() == "true";
    if (toolTip1.Tag != "true") e.Cancel = true;
    toolTip1.Tag = "false";
}
```

Comment: Well, Buttons behave just like Textboxes. Does it mean they are special too? Containers, DataGridViews, ListViews probably process differently the messages involved in displaying a ToolTip. It's undesirable that some controls associates the ToolTip with the control and some don't.

Comment: _Buttons behave just like Textboxes_ Not here. I can associate a ToolTip with a Button and it shows each time I hover over it. This doesn't work with a TextBox: Here the ToolTip is shown once and never more..

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. I can associate a ToolTip with a TextBox and is shown every time I hover over it (`toolTip.SetToolTip(textBox1, "bla")`), just like for a button. Here the ToolTip was supposed to be shown once and never more, but for some reason the DataGridView also associates with it and it shows every time I hover over it.

Comment: Hm, strange! I can't get the TextBox to show the ToolTip when I hover.. The MouseHover fires fine but the ToolTip never gets shown! - FYI I have added a flag-based alternative, that uses the PopUp event of the ToolTip..

Comment: Hm, this is bizarre. When you hover over the TextBox for the first time, the ToolTip is not shown, but if you move the mouse cursor within the box and stop again it will show.